# Enforce child entity uniqueness?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the best way to enforce a child entity to be unique?  For instance, lets say I have a Customer entity and a child entity collection called MarketingCampaign

```
public class Customer
{   
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MarketingCampaign> MarketingCampaigns { get; set; }

}

public class MarketingCampaign
{   
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Lets say that if a customer has the same MarketingCampaign added twice then it would be very bad as they would receive duplicate material.

In my code I could check if it exists before adding it but that relies on everyone knowing it must be unique.

Is there a way to force this on the model (preferably with data annotations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a one-to-zero-or-one relationship.

You can indeed use DataAnnotations to accomplish what you're trying to do, but you should have an intermediary table that tracks the customer / campaign relationship and has a FK back to a Campaign table. Then with the magic of Entity Framework, it `CustomerMarketingCampaignId` will be both the PK of `CustomerMarketingCampaign` and FK back to `Customer`

```
public class Customer
{   
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerMarketingCampaign> CustomerMarketingCampaign { get; set; }

}

public class CustomerMarketingCampaign
{   
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerMarketingCampaignId
    [ForeignKey("Campaign")]
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }

}

public class Campaign
{
    public int CampaignId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of creating and assigning?

Answer (score 0):

My final solution for posterity:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerMarketingCampaign> CustomerMarketingCampaigns { get; set; }
}
public class MarketingAction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerMarketingCampaign
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_CustomerAndMarketing", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_CustomerAndMarketing", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int MarketingActionID { get; set; }

    // I also have several properties not included for tracking the progress of the campaign

    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MarketingActionID")]
    public virtual MarketingAction MarketingAction { get; set; }
}
```